# command line tool for generating pdfs from various document types?

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

I'm looking for ways to generate PDFs on-the-fly, preferably using a command line tool, as this will be done from a web-based system.

My requirements include must work on Windows and Linux, should be able to convert Microsoft Word, Excel and HTML into PDF.

Also, the ability to concatenate or merge various documents into one PDF output file would be good.

Any suggestions? I would prefer to avoid applications that work as "printer drivers".

Comment: It seems that ImageMagick (which I'm already using with my application) can convert jpg to pdf, and also merge files. So that solves one part of the problem. I'm looking into OpenOffice plus PyODConverter to handle the other document types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After doing some research, the best solution I found in the end that could handle all the file formats we needed converting, plus which ran on Linux and Windows was a beautifully elegant lightweight Python script called PyODConverter. This uses OpenOffice (which itself runs in server mode) to do the actual conversions, and it really works beautifully. I used a separate tool called PDFTK to do the PDF concatenation, as I found that ImageMagick loses a lot of information (and creates huge file sizes).

If you find PyODConverter too limited, there is also a more powerful heavyweight option written by the same guy called JODConverter.

Answer (score 1):

[Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com) runs on Linux, Windows, and Mac OS X and has [command line tools](http://calibre-ebook.com/user_manual/cli/cli-index.html) on all three.  It can translate [a great many document types](http://calibre-ebook.com/user_manual/faq.html#e-book-format-conversion) to PDF and other formats.

(Disclaimer:  I'm a heavy user, help out on Calibre's IRC channel, and have been poking at development, so I'm just a bit biased.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It looks very good, but unfortunately it doesn't appear to support the Microsoft formats which is a key requirement of mine. Anyway I've long since implemented a great solution using PyODConverter. I guess I should add my own answer to the question :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think this has a command line utility, but not sure. Check this

[PDF Creator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfcreator/)

Comment: Thanks but I would prefer to avoid applications that work as "printer drivers" and also that appears to be Windows only.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [biopdf](http://www.biopdf.com/guide/index.php), and a PDF printer that uses it called [Bullzip PDF](http://www.bullzip.com/products/pdf/info.php).  Check the documentation for Bullzip PDF for examples on how it can be automated.  It has an API interface as well as the GUI.

Comment: Thanks but I would prefer to avoid applications that work as "printer drivers" and also that appears to be Windows only.